# Error with pip install scikit-image

Tags: python, installation, pip, scikit-image

I am using Windows 8.1 64 bit and Python 2.7. While trying to install `scikit-image` from the shell

`pip install scikit-image`

I have encountered this error:

`Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\france~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-buildtksnfe\scikit-image\`

The download is fine but the installation fails. **What is the problem here and how to solve it?**

**EDIT**

After upgrading my pip with

`python -m pip install -U pip setuptools`

and trying again, I got:

`Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\france~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-nbemct\scikit-image\`

What is wrong?

Comment: It didn't work anyway.

Comment: Please check if you have installed numpy and scipy first.

Comment: Try to install python compiler [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266)

Comment: I had numpy installed but was still getting error, so I tried this py -3 -m pip install -U pip setuptools and then py -3 -m pip install scikit-image it worked

Answer (score 24, accepted):

install numpy first

```
pip install numpy
```

If you face installation issues for numpy, get the pre-built windows installers from [http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) for your python version (python version is different from windows version).

```
numpy 32-bit: numpy-1.11.1+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl

numpy 64-bit: numpy-1.11.1+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
```

Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required. If you need VC++ 9.0, then please get it from this link: [Microsoft VC++ 9.0 download](http://aka.ms/vcpython27)

Then install

```
pip install scikit-image
```

It will install the below list before installing scikit-image

pyparsing, six, python-dateutil, pytz, cycler, matplotlib, scipy, decorator, networkx, pillow, toolz, dask

If it fails at installation of scipy, follow below steps:
get the pre-built windows installers from [http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) for your python version (python version is different from windows version).

```
Scipy 32-bit: scipy-0.18.0-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl

Scipy 64-bit: scipy-0.18.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
```

If it fails saying **whl is not supported wheel on this platform** , then upgrade pip using **python -m pip install --upgrade pip** and try installing scipy

Now try

```
pip install scikit-image
```

It should work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade pip first

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

install numpy

```
pip install numpy
```

install scipy

```
pip install scipy
```

download build tools from C++ of version 14 or higher from the link

[Microsoft visual code C++ build tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/)