# Python Package ImportError in Windows 10

Tags: python

I am having difficulty installing Python Packages on Windows 10.The package name is Tabular..i have been trying over and over and it doesn't work out.her what i get when I try to install it using pip.Any help about it ?Thanks

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install tabular
Collecting tabular
  Using cached tabular-0.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
      File "c:\users\pc\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-5mggv5\tabular\setup.py", line 50, in 
        raise ImportError("distribute was not found and fallback to setuptools was not allowed")
    ImportError: distribute was not found and fallback to setuptools was not allowed

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\pc\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-5mggv5\tabular\

C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install distribute
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): distribute in c:\python27\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools>=0.7 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from distribute)

C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install --upgrade distribute
Requirement already up-to-date: distribute in c:\python27\lib\site-packages
Collecting setuptools>=0.7 (from distribute)
  Downloading setuptools-25.1.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (442kB)
    100% |################################| 450kB 191kB/s
Installing collected packages: setuptools
  Found existing installation: setuptools 25.1.1
    Uninstalling setuptools-25.1.1:
      Successfully uninstalled setuptools-25.1.1
Successfully installed setuptools-25.1.6
```

Comment: Did you try after upgrading distribute?

Comment: Known bug. https://github.com/yamins81/tabular/issues/6

Comment: distribute is up to date for me

Answer (score 0):

Tabular 0.1 has issues with Windows 10. Please fall back to 0.0.8

```
pip install tabular==0.0.8
```

**Edit**

For scipy installation on Windows 10 with python 2.7, instructions are at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38618044/5334188

Comment: thanks that work fine on python 2.7 but if I try to install it with anaconda still doesn't work out ..PS:I am using anconda because it supports scipy module

Comment: You can install scipy as well in python 2.7 Anaconda python version is bit heavy. Refer to instructions here for installing scipy - http://stackoverflow.com/a/38618044/5334188 if you want to stick to Anaconda python, please let me know to debug further

Comment: I try it to install scipy on python2.7 but doesn't work out that s why i went to anaconda.So is it possible toinstall tabular in anaconda

Comment: @Maisha are you still getting same error on anaconda?

Comment: yes i still i was looking around how to install tabular on anaconda but i can't find anything

Comment: @Maisha I have installed tabular==0.0.8 on anaconda, it is working for me.

Comment: here what i get when i try to install it (C:\Users\PC\Anaconda2) C:\Users\PC>conda install tabular==0.0.8
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: .
Error: Package missing in current win-64 channels:
  - tabular ==0.0.8

You can search for packages on anaconda.org with

    anaconda search -t conda tabular

Comment: well  i get this command "pip install -i https://pypi.anaconda.org/pypi/simple tabular==0.0.8" and now i have tabular installed in anaconda