# pip matplotlib module installation error windows 64 bit python

Tags: python

'Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Rakesh>pip isntall matplotlib
ERROR: unknown command "isntall" - maybe you meant "install"

C:\Users\Rakesh>pip install matplotlib
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached matplotlib-2.2.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ============================================================================
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

```
BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
            matplotlib: yes [2.2.2]
                python: yes [3.7.0b3 (v3.7.0b3:4e7efa9c6f, Mar 29 2018,
                        18:42:04) [MSC v.1913 64 bit (AMD64)]]
              platform: yes [win32]

REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                 numpy: yes [not found. pip may install it below.]
      install_requires: yes [handled by setuptools]
                libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                        be found. Using local copy.]
              freetype: no  [The C/C++ header for freetype
                        (freetype2\ft2build.h) could not be found.  You may
                        need to install the development package.]
                   png: no  [The C/C++ header for png (png.h) could not be
                        found.  You may need to install the development
                        package.]
                 qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'libqhull' could not
                        be found. Using local copy.]

OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
           sample_data: yes [installing]
              toolkits: yes [installing]
                 tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
        toolkits_tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]

OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
                qt5agg: no  [PySide2 not found; PyQt5 not found]
                qt4agg: no  [PySide not found; PyQt4 not found]
               gtk3agg: no  [Requires pygobject to be installed.]
             gtk3cairo: no  [Requires cairocffi or pycairo to be installed.]
                gtkagg: no  [Requires pygtk]
                 tkagg: yes [installing; run-time loading from Python Tcl /
                        Tk]
                 wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
                   gtk: no  [Requires pygtk]
                   agg: yes [installing]
                 cairo: no  [cairocffi or pycairo not found]
             windowing: yes [installing]

OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
                dvipng: no
           ghostscript: no
                 latex: no
               pdftops: no

OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
                  dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]

============================================================================
                        * The following required packages can not be built:
                        * freetype, png
                        * Please check http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packa
                        * ges/freetype.htm for instructions to install
                        * freetype
                        * Please check http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packa
                        * ges/libpng.htm for instructions to install png

----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Rakesh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-9bxd88gw\matplotlib\

C:\Users\Rakesh>Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1'

i tried installing using pip install matplotlib. it downloaded the module at the end it got this message. is there anyway to directly download and extract?
im getting this error message at the end. what should i do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install returns "python setup.py egg\_info" failed with error code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/pip-install-returns-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1)

Comment: so waht should i do @davedwards

Comment: it might be a problem with one or more dependencies of the packages you are installing. Check the `Traceback` for possible errors in dependencies of packages

Comment: possibly helpful or related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39060669/python-matplotlib-install-issue-on-windows-7-for-freetype-png-packages

Comment: i have no idea.. im a beginner can you guide me?

Comment: could you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49823462/edit) the question and include the complete Error message?

Comment: i have done it take a look @davedwards

Comment: Thanks. The output shows `freetype` and `png` packages are not installed. Try `pip install freetype png` as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39060880/1248974

Comment: " Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement png (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for png" this is the error i get

Comment: these errors might be related to the dependencies not yet compatible with Python preview release `3.7.0b3`. However, you might try `pip install libpng`

Answer (score 2):

Quickest way I solve any issue with pip installs on windows is use these precompiled packages.

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: where to extract and how to import after downloading?

Comment: You download the .whl file. Make sure its the right python version and bit architecture. And then you just pip install the whl file. "pip install matplotlib‑2.2.2‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl"

Comment: im using python 3.7 so what should i download and 64 bit system

Comment: matplotlib‑2.2.2‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl

Comment: You need to ensure your python is 64 bit too. open command prompt and type python. First line. Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

Has to say 64 bit

Comment: Or you'll just get another error. in which case use the 32 bit version. matplotlib‑2.2.2‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl

Comment: i use a 64 bit system, the downloaded .whl file should be moved to some location before installing? or i can directly enter the command?

Comment: Just enter the command. As long as you're in the same folder where the whl file is. You have to explicitly choose to download 64-bit python in order to get the 64 bit version of python. A vast majority are running 32 bit python on a 64 bit windows system.

Comment: i tried your method.. i got this "Command "c:\users\rakesh\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Rakesh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-mo__rf6c\\kiwisolver\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Rakesh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-cckmrox8-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Rakesh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-mo__rf6c\kiwisolver\"

Comment: Did you extract the wheel file, cause you don't need to extract anything. I'm confused why you asked about extracting. It's precompiled so you shouldn't be getting an error relating to setup.py. Is this the command you ran? pip install "matplotlib‑2.2.2‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl"

Comment: yes that is the cmd i ran from the .whl downloaded location.. i got that error

Comment: Not sure. You might want to try switching to anaconda like the other answer suggested. It creates an environment which might work better for you. Or just use python 3.6. I don't have any issues with 3.6

Answer (score 0):

some packages like matplotlib will be easier to install from this URL: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
the better way is to install anaconda from the URL below:
https://www.anaconda.com/download/

Comment: where to extract and how to import after downloading?

Answer (score 0):

Install Anaconda. To do so, download
https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.1.0-Windows-x86_64.exe
and install it.

Then, you can install matplotlib using the Anaconda Navigator or using the following command line from the shell:

```
conda install matplotlib
```

I advise you to work with Anaconda (or something equivalent). It ships pre-built packages, and its very convenient in a Windows environment where building some packages (numpy, scipy, ...) can be very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issues with Python 3.7 and 3.6.5 and laters...

Actually even when I solved the above I had other issues to install python-crfsuite and Tensorflow:

Got:

```
error: invalid argument '-std=c99' not allowed with 'C++/ObjC++'
```

**The only thing** that worked for me was to run with **Python 3.6.4**

Go to [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/) to install 3.6.4 and try again.

Or do it with Conda/Anaconda [here](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html)

If you are facing issues with pkgs that you had on Python3.7 and you have mac try solving it with:

[python location on mac osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819661/python-location-on-mac-osx/51367161#51367161)